# What mail sever can I use for linuxmint for send email from localhost?

Tags: linux-mint

I am using **linuxmint Os**. I want to send **email** from local host.

Please suggest me a good compatible **mail server**.

What mail server can I use ?

How to install and configure ?

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: What did your research for a possible solution bring up? Did the found suggestions work for you?

Comment: I have found required solution by install mail server in localhost. But i can't installed mail server in my local system.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a so-called [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent). If you only need to send outgoing mail, `sendmail` should be sufficient. Otherwise, have a look at Postfix, it's relatively easy to set up and configure.

Note: When you operate a mail server on a public machine, make sure it cannot be abused as *open relay*!

Comment: When i am installing any mail server packages it can't installed and always show error. `Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`

Comment: Oh, come on. Please use Google, these are issues that may have a thousand reasons and have been solved a thousand times.